# TinyMCE only shows simple textarea box when run from PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have TinyMCE working perfectly from a single php script but when I break it down to be included in my site from a PHP function, I only get a blank textarea box. After several tests I have come to the conclusion that the issue is URL passing from TinyMCE. The codes below work flawlessly:
//localhost/include/textarea.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#addingTextarea",
        theme: "modern",
        menubar: "false",
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        plugins: [
            "smileys textcolor wordcount "
        ],
        toolbar1: "fontselect |  fontsizeselect | bold | italic | forecolor | backcolor | smileys",
        image_advtab: false,
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
include'../include/textareafunc.php';
TextAreastart();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

localhost/include/textareafunc.php

```
<?php
function TextAreastart()
{
    TextAreaNew();
}

function TextAreaNew()
{
?>
<form method="post" action="somepage">
    <textarea id="addingTextarea" name="content3" style="width:90%"></textarea>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Yes the functions seem redundant but I wanted to complicate it to guarantee it would work for my purposes. The result is a properly functioning TinyMCE textrea. However, when I C&P the two Javascripts to my localhost/index.php in the HEAD and call for the Textareastart function from localhost/include/profilefunc.php, all I get is that cursed textarea with no TinyMCE features.
I have checked the TinyMCE site and found something about the URL directions, so I attempted to modify my JavaScript in localhost/index.php as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#addingTextarea",
        theme: "modern",
        menubar: "false",
        relative_urls: true,
        document_base_url: 'http://localhost/tinymce/',
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        plugins: [
            "smileys textcolor wordcount "
        ],
        toolbar1: "fontselect |  fontsizeselect | bold | italic | forecolor | backcolor | smileys",
        image_advtab: false,
    });
</script>
```

as well as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#addingTextarea",
        theme: "modern",
        menubar: "false",
        relative_urls: true,
        document_base_url: 'http://localhost/tinymce/',
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        plugins: [
            "smileys textcolor wordcount "
        ],
        toolbar1: "fontselect |  fontsizeselect | bold | italic | forecolor | backcolor | smileys",
        image_advtab: false,
    });
});
</script>
```

but it changes nothing. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: I really need to solve this. TinyMCE forum isn't panning out for answers so I'm relying on you guys

Answer (score 0):

Issue: you have initialized tinymce before your php function and when it searched for your textarea id .. it didn't get that id till that time. because you are including your php function after tinymce. So

Just DO the little change:

Include your php file before initializing tinymce.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    </head>    
    <body>
    <?php
    include'../include/textareafunc.php';
    TextAreastart();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#addingTextarea",
            theme: "modern",
            menubar: "false",
            theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
            font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
            plugins: [
                "smileys textcolor wordcount "
            ],
            toolbar1: "fontselect |  fontsizeselect | bold | italic | forecolor | backcolor | smileys",
            image_advtab: false,
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: same result. runs well on its own but fails when run from an 'include'

Comment: do you really need to that using include. if so. then try to put together both your `textarea` and `tinymce.init` and then include. OR try without using include.